# Discovering which records of a batch update failed

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i am making a batch update of 1000 records in java using jdbc. Out of them 800 records were updated sucessfully and 200 falied . so i want to check from batch update query that which all 200 records were failed to b updated and i will insert them in database using batch insert . how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Doesn't your batch query return an int array reflecting the records updated?

Comment: yes it does but I want to know which all records were not updated

Comment: All records which have value 0 in the  returned array

Answer (score 2):

`executeBath()` method from `Statement` returns an array of integers (one integer per command that was executed). Each integer represents update count. If 1 or greater, update was done successfully; if 0, no record was updated with its respective command.

Example:

```
List<YourClass> objectsToUpdate = getObjectsToUpdate();

for (YourClass object : objectsToUpdate) {
    String updateCommand = generateUpdateCommand(object);
    statement.addBatch(updateCommand);
}
int[] results = statement.executeBatch();

List<YourClass> notUpdated = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i] == 0) {
        notUpdated.add(objectsToUpdate.get(i));
    }
}
```

That was just to demonstrate the algorithm. Consider using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`.

Comment: but which records that were not updated (query failed) I want to retrieve them. how can I?

Comment: something like this: having a list/array of objects, you generate a command per object and call addBatch(), then call executeBatch(), that returns an array. Then you iterate and check if item is 0. If is 0, object in corresponding array index was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, it's also important to say that when using batch updates, a JDBC driver may also return (as part of the integer array) Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO (when no information on updated rows is available) or Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED (when an exception occurs)

Some JDBC drivers may even stop executing further statements (updates) in case of an exception.